# Does weak convergence $x_n$ to $x$ imply weak convergence of $y_n = \|x_n\|x_n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ be weakly convergent.
Does the sequence $y_n := \|x_n\| x_n$ converge weakly?

It's just a small exercise from an old exam. However I was not able to find a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: Yes. Weak convergence implies boundedness of the norms.

Comment: Hi, this is something i know and I also tried to use this to prove the statement, but I didn't get it.

Comment: In $c_0$, look at $e_1, e_1+2e_2, e_1+e_3, e_1+2e_4, \ldots$, where $e_i$ is the $i$'th standard unit vector.

Comment: If $x_n$ is the sequence from your comment, then $x_n \rightharpoonup e_1$. But $y_n$   has subsequence converging weakly to $e_1$ and a subsequence converging weakly to $2e_1$. So obviously $y_n$ doesn't converge weakly.
Thank you!